# PM2 not keeping node.js applications online 24/7

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, discord.js, pm2

I believe PM2 was supposed to keep node.js applications 24/7. However, once I shut down my computer my node.js application (a discord bot) goes to sleep. Does anybody know how to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: and one more thing about StackOverflow community, don't forget to mark question as answered, just to close the question, it provided solution was helpful and your case is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it a bit wrong.

`PM2` is just a process manager, and there are many others, like [`node-demon`](https://nodemon.io/). So it has nothing to do with your own computer, in this certain case.

It helps you, to run/manage your app on other server (for example VPS/VDS), right after `ssh` connecting. So you should launch process there, and then, right after disconnecting the session, you process won't go shutdown, if you use `pm2`

If you want your discord bot working 24/7, even when your own computer offline, shutdown or so, take a look at:

1. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
2. [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) (free tier)
3. [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/free) (free tier)
4. [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Rent any service / VPS, connect to it via `ssh` or `sftp`, place your binary files there, in your case it should be `node.js` project, and then launch.

> Don't forget to run `npm install pm2 -g` on the remote server and `npm install` before this operation.

But not via `npm start`, as usual but via `pm2 start [name]`.

In that case, pm2 will manage your process, and your discord bot still is online, even if you disconnect from the server.

You might wanna take a look at it, via `pm2 monit` command, it gives you such output: [image]

Comment: @MrOOF600 Also, one more thing, just to be sure. The `^latest` version of pm2 doesn't support the `cron` job. It's a bug and it's not been fixed over a year or so. So you'll write your own `*.yaml` file and your cron tasks won't work, it's not your fault, it's a bug.

Comment: @MrOOF600 also, for a look at `Heroku`. Discord bots aren't so resourceful, so it's a perfect start for you. And then, you could scale it via any cloud platform.